# How to create a local migration file for my containerized flask app

Tags: python, flask, flask-migrate

I recently containerized my flask app. My docker-compose file creates four containers: web, db, rabbit and celery.  My web container updates when I update my code.  It works great and I'm happy with it.

However, I feel like I must be missing something because I can't figure out how to create a migration file.  When I was using a virtual env, I just ran `python manage.py db migrate` and (boom!) the migration was created.  Now when I fire up my venv and run that command, I get the following error:

```
(psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "db" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I suppose this makes sense since the command/code can't seem find/resolve the `db`.  With that said, how do I solve this?  Am I going about this incorrectly?

I'm using: SQLAlchemy, flask-migrate, postgres

Comment: You must run manage.py in the container, something among the lines `docker-compose exec container-name /path/to/manage.py db migrate`.

Comment: @narunasK - I guess that makes sense.  However, don't I want the migration file to be local as well?  If so, how?  If not, why not?

Comment: @hugo Just mount a volume on the container and put your app in that volume. Now everything that's written to the volume in the container can be accessed from the host, and in some cases, from other conatainers.

Comment: @narunasK - your suggestions were spot on.  Once I created the volume, I rebuilt my containers...then ran the migration command you suggested on my web container and the new migration file popped up in my local environment.  Thanks so much!

Comment: I've assembled my comments into the answer, please accept it if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must run `manage.py` in the container, something among the lines should do:

```
docker-compose exec container-name /path/to/manage.py db migrate
```

If you need access to the files created in your container just mount a volume on the container and pack your app into that volume. Everything that's written to the volume within the container can be accessed from the host.